# is there any Replacement of inputDefaults(CakePHP) in CakePHP3?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3, cakephp-3.0

In CakePHP2 we use FormHelper's inputDefault options to set default values for all input within form 
For Example :

```
  echo $this->Form->create('User', array(
        'inputDefaults' => array(
            'required' => false,
            'error' => false,
            'div' => 'form-group',
            'label' => false
        )
    ));
```

But i am not finding any option in CakePHP3 helper like this, they haven't mentioned removed it or not?

Is anybody there, who know about this....

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [migration guide](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/3-0-migration-guide.html#formhelper) `inputDefaults` option was removed.

> - The `inputDefaults` option has been removed from `create()`.
> - `FormHelper::inputDefaults()` has been removed. You can use `templates()` to define/augment the templates `FormHelper` uses.

`templates()` method of `FormHelper` documentation you can find [here](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#customizing-the-templates-formhelper-uses).